# Проблема с кодировкой кириллицы темы письма, отправителя и названия вложенных файлов при отправке через phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Письмо приходит с темой Ð—Ð°Ñ Ð²ÐºÐ° Ð½Ð° Ñ€Ð°Ñ Ñ‡ÐµÑ, также отображает имя отправителя и названия вложенных файлов (если названия кириллические). В PHPmailer установлена кодировка UTF-8, кодировка самого файла со скриптом тоже UTF-8. В теле письма кириллический текст отображается так как нужно. Вот сам скрипт отправки:

```
$from_name = 'МЕТРОТАЙЛ';
$subject_name = 'Заявка на расчет #0';  

require(__DIR__ .'/PHPMailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
try {
$mail->charSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setFrom('info@test.com', $from_name);
$mail->addAddress('info@test.com');
if ($_POST['customEmail']) { 
$mail->addAddress($customEmail);
};
$mail->Subject = $subject_name.''.$next_id;
for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addStringAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}
$mail->msgHTML('Файлы во вложении');


$mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Я пробовал транслитерацию, но желаемого результата это не дало.

Comment: Попробуйте выгрузить сообщение в файл перед отправкой. Посмотрите, верно ли в файле письма выставлены заголовки.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Я пробовал передавать тему, отправителя и названия файлов в тело письма и там все отображается правильно http://prntscr.com/jz047u

Comment: Попробуйте тему задать так $mail->Subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject_name.''.$next_id) . '?=';

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Спасибо большое, получилось исправить с темой письма и отправителем. Но как быть с названиями файлов?

Comment: используйте транслит

Comment: @OlegGerasimenko Возьмите продвинутый мейлер типа SwiftMailer. Там с аттачментами точно проблем нету

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Спасибо, на будущее буду использовать SwiftMailer. Но у меня получилось исправить названия файлов, добавив Вашу подсказку к $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($filename).'?=');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение

```
$from_name = 'МЕТРОТАЙЛ';
$subject_name = 'Заявка на расчет #0';  

require(__DIR__ .'/PHPMailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
try {
$mail->charSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setFrom('info@test.com', '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($from_name).'?=');
$mail->addAddress('info@test.com');
if ($_POST['customEmail']) { 
$mail->addAddress($customEmail);
};
$mail->Subject =  '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject_name.''.$next_id).'?=';

for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($filename).'?=');
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}
$mail->msgHTML('Файлы во вложении');

$mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле достаточно обратиться к правильному свойству (в коде ошибка в имени свойства), например:

```
$mail->CharSet = $mail::CHARSET_UTF8;
```

(по умолчанию стоит public $CharSet = self::CHARSET_ISO88591;)